# Поиск по приложению на C#

Tags: c#, search, uwp, desktop

Имею полностью десктопное приложение на C#/UWP. Представляет собой что-то типа Google Maps, только проще, и карта только одного этажа здания. В здании есть комнаты с именами, они занесены в массив. Никакой базы данных нет. Пытаюсь реализовать поиск по-типу Google Search Engine. Доходя до последнего элемента массива выходит ошибка, хотя до этого элементы добавлялись в dropdown.
[image: Изображение]

[Вот](http://pastebin.com/aXs20Nn7) мой код.

Не судите строго, я учусь!

---

---

P.S: Как поместить картинку под спойлер? Не очень понятно написано про ">!" знак.

Comment: имена в массиве string[]? и есть поле ввода, в нем набирают например: "ко" и вам надо в string[] найти все строки, в которых есть "ко"?

Comment: Вот и выросло поколение. Для поиска по подстроке в десятках строк без базы данных и движка поиска уже никуда.

Comment: @Discord поиск у меня есть, но он работает криво и его нужно полировать. Сроки жмут, проект надо сдать, поэтому прошу не судить строго

Comment: @DavidArutiunian _"поиск у меня есть, но он работает криво"_ -- что не работает?

Comment: @DavidArutiunian Уф. Опишите, что вы хотели получить, что сделали, что получили, и в чём у вас проблема с исправлением ситуации. Сейчас формулировка на уровне "хочу того, не знаю чего".

Comment: @Discord я создам новый вопрос, там изложу проблему.

Comment: @DavidArutiunian не нужно создавать новый вопрос. В этом вопросе нажмите кнопку "править" под вопросом и добавьте все необходимые изменения.

Comment: @DavidArutiunian для поиска в строке см. [String.IndexOf](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.string.indexof(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: @Discord посмотрите пожалуйста. Ввел первую букву в строке поиска L , она же word[0]. Она сравнивается со всеми названиями. Если буква какого либо названия совпадает с введённой буквой то это название добавляется в список. При последнем проходе программа вылетает.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

При каждом изменении текста в textBox, вы будете создавать новую комнату и заново инициализировать список комнат. Зачем?
Создайте один раз и добавьте список. Если нужно обновить, то заведи специальный метод.

### **Сам поиск.**

Зачем этот велосипед? Как уже сказали есть String.IndexOf. В аргумент метода передаете нужную подстроку, и метод вернет индекс этой строки, если она присутствует в искомой, иначе вернет -1.
Весь код нужно заменить на использование этого метода, если, конечно, нужен именно такой поиск.

Еще рекомендации.

### Класс Room.

1. Название. Класс называется комната, и в тоже время объект этого класса будет содержать список комнат. Странно, правда? Это скорее всего класс Building.
2. Поля я бы сделал приватными. И обвернул их в свойства.
3. Инициализация списка комнат. Поэлементная инициализация уже для 15
   элементов ужасна тем, что можно ошибиться: легко пропустить элемент:

// ...
idname[15] = "F6141";
idname[17] = "Parts of Utility"; // 16 элемент пропущен
// ...

Поэтому это дело, лучше выполнять в приватном методе.

```
private int counter = 0;
private void AddName(string name) {
    idname[counter++] = name;
}
```

Хотя это не нужно: есть много стандартных средств. Поэтому я бы заменил массив на List:

```
public class Building {
    public List<string> RoomNames { get; private set; }
    public Building() {
        RoomNames = new List<string>(100);
        InitNames();
    }
    private void InitNames() {
        RoomNames.Add("IT-Robotolab");
        RoomNames.Add("LEP1-2");
        // ...
    }
}
```

Да и комнату, лучше создать, как отдельный класс:

```
class Room {
    public string Name { get; private set; }
    //...
}
```

**Ну, и самое главное, вы не используете паттерн MVVM.**

P.S. Такое ощущение, что Вы писали до этого немного на си, и сейчас начали писать на шарпе.

**UPD**
Почему же вылетает exception?
Вся проблема из-за инициализации. При объявлении массива вы задаете ему размер 100, а значит в массиве будет находится 100 элементов со значением по умолчанию для типа массива, в нашем случае, это string, и пожтому все элементы в начале будут иметь значение null.
Затем Вы заменяете первые 16 пустых элементов на какие-то другие. Но в массиве также по прежнему 100 элементов: первые 16, которые заменили, и оставшиеся 84 - пустых.
В цикле:

```
for (i = 0; i < room.idname.Length; i++)
{
//...
}
```

Вы проходите по всем, 100-ам, элементам. И на 17 элементе получаете exception, т.к. его значение у него null, и вы на null пытаетесь вызвать метод ToCharArray();

С использованием списка проблем таких не будет.

Comment: Всё верно, писал на Си. В вашем решении буду разбираться. Заранее благодарен!

Comment: Чуть позже опишу, почему был exception

Comment: Я уже разобрался. у меня же был массив из 100 стрингов, но по факту их было 16. Всю систему переделал, использую String.IndexOf. Спасибо всем большое! Буду читать про MVVM. Что-то новое для меня

Comment: @DavidArutiunian, не увидел комментарий, в это время писал. Хорошо, что разобрались. Удачи!